# Como colocar eventos a una etiqueta <object> para crear un boton html

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, javascript-objeto

**Me gustaria crear un boton html con animaciones svg de fondo, con la etiqueta  y stilos css logro un efecto interesante, pero no logro darle eventos con  javascript a la etiqueta "<object"

**

```
 <object  onclick="cambioslaider()" class="botoninicio" data="https://animacionesweb.online/animaciones/pecera.svg"></object>
 .botoninicio {
                   color: #ffffff;
                 border-radius: 18px;
                background: #303030;
                width:100px;
                height:50px;
                cursor: pointer;
                    margin:3px;
             background: #303030;
            border: 2px solid #0016b0;
            }      
            
            
            function cambioslaider(){
                console.log("me llaman");
                alert("me llaman");
            
            }
```

Comment: Que clase de eventos intentas ejecutar?

Comment: de momento un simple onclick, pero realizado sobre la animación https://codepen.io/jose-manuel-mateos/pen/WNrGWGy

Comment: Esta informacion te sera de utilidad, sabes de que me di cuenta?, de que si le das a los bordes e intentas clickearlos funciona.

Comment: si lo se, pero no logro nada para que haciendo clik sobre la animacion funcionase, gracias pro tu interes